# Regex for SQL Injection patterns in a JSP source code in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to create a regex to look for SQL Injection patterns in a JSP source code. I'm using the Notepad++ Find in Files functionality and I want to find a pattern across hundreds of files. Pattern would look something like this:

1) First part the file must contain any of these:

- doGet
- doPost
- doPut
- doDelete
- doCopy
- doOptions

2) Secondly the file must contain (note this can be String or Integer):

**String foo = request.getParameter("bar");**

3)Thirdly the file must also contain

**select...where...+...foo...**

Notice in the third part the SQL Statement is using the parameter set on the second part.

Another important note is that, there may be N amount of characters, new lines, returns, lines of code, or what have you, between each part.

Using https://regexr.com/ I came up with the following regex:

`^.*doGet.*[\r\n]*.*String\s(.*)\s\=\srequest.getParameter.*[\r\n]*.*select.*where.*\+.*\1`

Which matches the for example:

```
doGet();

String foo = request.getParameter('bar');

String qry = "select * from test where id =" + foo;
```

However it does not match:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{ 
code = code.code;
test = test.test;
donothing();
}

String foo = request.getParameter('bar');


if(foo){
String qry = "select * from test where id =" + foo;
}
```

Comment: You can try something like [`this`](https://regex101.com/r/dm03Le/1/)

Comment: Is grep an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Code Maniac

`^.*?doGet[\w\W]+?String ([^=]+) = request\.getParameter[\w\W]+?select.*where[^+]+\+ \1`

Seems like it was the best answer that produced the least amount of false positives.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with

```
(?=.*do(?:Get|Post|Put|Delete|Copy|Options)).*(?:String|Integer)\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*=\s*request\.getParameter\(\s*(["'])(?:\\.|(?!\2)[^\\])*\2\s*\)\s*;.*select.*where.*\+.*\1
```

make shure to activae the '. matches newline' checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty complicated, yet maybe you might want to design an expression, close to:

```
(?i).*\bdoGet\b[\s\S]*?String\s+(\S+)\s*=\s*request\.getParameter\(['"]bar['"]\)\s*;[\s\S]*?\bselect\s+.*\bfrom\b.*\bwhere\s+.*(\1)\s*;(?:[\r\n]*\})?
```

which would likely fail in some instances, by the way.

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pJPd6t/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/pJPd6t/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.